# CKEditor allow <span> inside <a> tag

Tags: html, ckeditor

I want to add `<span>` tag inside of an `<a>` tag in the CKEditor source:

```
<a href="http://google.com"><span>Link here</span></a>
```

But when I add the HTML in CKEditor in source mode, it converts it to:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Link Here</a>
```

How can I allow HTML tags inside a `href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do u really need to put the `<span>` tags in there? Isn't it better to add a class to your link and edit it(the css I guess u want) from there.

**What u can do:**

1. Try doing it the other way: `<span><a href="http://google.com">Link here</a></span>`
2. Open your html file in Notepad/PSpad or anything that always shows you the rare source code and try to write it there - shouldn't be a problem.
3. As I already wrote up - if u want that span there for editing css of the link text - use class in your link and edit css values. **Example:** `<a href="http://google.com" class="myLink">Link Here</a>` and in **css**: `.myLink { ...your custom setting... }`

If you could tell us for what you need the span tags there it would help us answering you :)

P.S.: I'm sorry that I'm not answering about the editor you are using. I just think you might want to try other editors that don't disable stuff u usually can do when writing the code.

Comment: CKEditor by default disables stuff which is not supposed to be allowed. This `<span>` is a piece of crappy non-semantic HTML soup and in default configuration CKEditor won't allow it (although it can be configured not to do that). You can read more about [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter).

Comment: @Reinmar well the thing that Vijay wanted to do isn't invalid.. But I agree it's not a good/pretty solution. That's why I recommended other way of dealing with links formatting and wanted to know why exactly he wants to do this(just in case it wasn't for the formatting).

Answer (score 7):

This `<span>` is removed by [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter). Apparently (and this is not surprising) none of features enabled in your editor allows bare spans (which are crappy non-semantic HTML), so they are simply removed.

I advice you not to use such messy HTML, because CKEditor will at some point break your `<a>+<span>` doublets because it does not know that they should be edited together.

However, if you need to use them, then check these options: [config.allowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter-property-allowedContent) or [config.extraAllowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent). First one allows to completely disable Advanced Content Filter.

Answer (score 7):

Use [extraAllowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent) filter:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor', {
    extraAllowedContent: 'a span',
});
```