# CKEditor: Allow span tag inside paragraph

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.7.x

If I enter and save the following html to CKEditor all span tags gets removed.

```
 <p class="animate" data-animate="fadeIn"><span>Maschinenlager</span> <span>Schwergutlager</span> <span>Frei- vs. Festplatzprinzip</span></p>
```

I found the [following solution on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300990/ckeditor-allow-span-inside-a-tag) adapt it for my needs but it doesn´t work.

```
 editor:
   config:
    extraAllowedContent: "*(*)[data-*];span;p span"
```

I used the default config from EXT an include it in my own.

```
 imports:
- { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Processing.yaml" }
- { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Base.yaml" }
- { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Plugins.yaml" }
```

Tags are allowed from default config.

```
  processing:
    allowTags:
      - a
      - abbr
      - acronym
      - address
      - article
      - big
      - blockquote
      - br
      - caption
      - cite
      - code
      - col
      - colgroup
      - dd
      - del
      - dfn
      - dl
      - div
      - dt
      - em
      - footer
      - header
      - h1
      - h2
      - h3
      - h4
      - h5
      - h6
      - hr
      - i
      - img
      - ins
      - kbd
      - label
      - li
      - nav
      - ol
      - p
      - pre
      - q
      - samp
      - section
      - small
      - span
      - strong
      - style
      - sub
      - sup
      - table
      - thead
      - tbody
      - tfoot
      - td
      - th
      - tr
      - tt
      - ul
      - var
```

How can i archive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the span tag is not allowed in your configuration? Then add it like this:

```
# Allow additional tags
processing:
  allowTags:
    - s
    - span
    - iframe
    - i
```

**EDIT:** It seems to be necessary you add the span to extraAllowedContent:

```
editor:
  config:
    extraAllowedContent:
      - span
```

And much more important, to prevent empty tags to become stripped away:

```
processing:
  HTMLparser_db:
    tags:
      span:
        rmTagIfNoAttrib: false
```

Comment: This doesn´t work for me. I had this in my config see edited question.

Comment: Updated my answer since I ran into the same problem these days.

Comment: rmTagIfNoAttrib: false was the important part. Thanks for your help ;-)